# Transform elements in column with the column name as argument

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to modify the data in a data set based on a vector of columns to change. That way I could factorize the treatment based on a config file which would have the list of columns to change as a variable.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use ddply like that :

```
column <- "var2"
df <- ddply(df, .(), transform, column = func(column))
```

The output would be the same dataframe but in the column "B", each letter would have an "A" added behind it

Which would change each element of the column var2 by the element through func (func here is used to trim a chr in a particular way). I've tried several solutions, like :

```
df[do.call(func, df[,column]), ]
```

which doesn't accept the df[,column] as argument (not a list), or

```
param = c("var1", "var2")
for(p in param){
    df <- df[func(df[,p]),]
}
```

which destroys the other data, or

```
df[, column] <- lapply(df[, column], func)
```

Which doesn't work because it takes the whole column as argument instead of changing each element 1 by 1. I'm kinda out of ideas on how to make this treatment more automatic.

Example :

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=letters[2:11])
colname <- "B"
addA <- function(text) { paste0(text, "A") }
```

And I would like to do something like this :

```
df <- ddply(df, .(), transform, colname = addA(colname))
```

Though if the solution does not use ddply, it's not an issue, it's just what I'm the most used to

Comment: Does `df[,column] <- do.call(func, list(df[,column]))` get you the result you're after?

Comment: The issue in that case is that all the elements of the column end up as the same, instead of each being from 'its' row

Comment: Can you add a minimal example to your question?  This would include a function you want to use and a dataset (or use a built in dataset) and the desired output.

Comment: @aosmith : Added an example, I hope it is clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `mutate_at` from package *dplyr* for this.

```
library(dplyr)

mutate_at(df, colname, addA)

    A  B
1   1 bA
2   2 cA
3   3 dA
4   4 eA
5   5 fA
6   6 gA
7   7 hA
8   8 iA
9   9 jA
10 10 kA
```